# SPARQL: Converting CONSTRUCT Query w/ Named Graph to SELECT Query

Tags: sparql, rdf, allegrograph, named-graphs

You are not able to specify a **GRAPH** in a **CONSTRUCT** query with **SPARQL 1.1**

```
CONSTRUCT {
  GRAPH <graph:1> { ?s rdf:type ?o . }
}
WHERE {
  GRAPH <graph:1> { ?s rdf:type ?o . }
  VALUES (?o) { (<class:1>) (<class:2>) }
}
```

- I will refer to the query above as a **GRAPH CONSTRUCT** query

My thought is that it is possible to get the expected result by converting the **GRAPH CONSTRUCT** query to a **SELECT** query. It is common for us to expect an array of length 4 representing an RDF quad, therefore having the ability to **CONSTRUCT** with a **GRAPH** would be helpful.

The procedure of the conversion is less meaningful, I am more so interested in the format of the result from a **GRAPH CONSTRUCT** query to a **SELECT** query, taking into consideration all corner cases.

I would also appreciate an answer which explains why it is too difficult to do so with a **SELECT** query.

---

### Question

How would a **SELECT** query be formatted with respect to a **GRAPH CONSTRUCT** query, considering all corner cases?

We will assume that the **SELECT** query results will roughly be converted to **GRAPH CONSTRUCT** results as shown below, but we will not be worrying about the format of the variables being tracked or the procedure of this conversion.

```js
// Variables which are tracked to construct quads
const tracked = { "?V0": ["?s", "?V1", "?o"] };

// 'constructQuery' is converted to 'selectQuery'
const selectQuery = convertGraphConstructToSelect(constructQuery);

// SPARQL is executed on 'selectQuery'
const result = executeSparql(selectQuery);

// Returns expected result of GRAPH CONSTRUCT
const quads = constructFromSelect(tracked, result);
```

- Pseudocode roughly representing process of getting **GRAPH CONSTRUCT** results

### Example Answer

(In reference to the **GRAPH CONSTRUCT** query at the top)

```
SELECT ?V0 ?s ?V1 ?o
WHERE {
  GRAPH ?V0 { ?s ?V1 ?o . }
  VALUES (?o) { (<class:1>) (<class:2>) }
  VALUES (?V0 ?V1) { (<graph:1> rdf:type) }
}
```

- All literals in the **GRAPH CONSTRUCT** are converted to unique variables
- Each instance of converted literals in the **WHERE** are converted to those unique variable names.
- A **VALUES** block is added to the end of the **WHERE** which represents all of the converted literals

Comment: Yes, it's not possible in SPARQL CONSTRUCT to create quads i.e. specify the graph. Andy Seaborne did some extension in Apache Jena [(link)](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/query/construct-quad.html), but you're using Allegrograph as I can see from the tags. But, what is the question now?

Comment: I think it may matter *why* you want to do this, as this seems like either a theory question (which is fine, but should be flagged as such) or an [XY Problem](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node=XY+Problem) (which would be best answered with a different tactic than with a solution to your question as written).

Comment: @TallTed I want this to be a guide for those who want to implement a `GRAPH CONSTRUCT` into their system. I don't want the question to be too open-ended, and so I gave an example of how the variables might be tracked to convert from the `SELECT` results to the expected `GRAPH CONSTRUCT` results.